# UIAtionSheet with UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I need some suggestions about UIActionSheet. In my case I have created an ActionSheet in which I am displaying the UITableView with some data.

```
UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
[asheet showInView:self.view]; 
[asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 320)];


CustomView *innerView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
innerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 210);

[asheet addSubview:innerView.view];
```

the CustomView contains the table . Data is displaying properly, it displays exact 3 rows, now I want some similar functionality like :
(1) when I click on any row, the selected row should come at center.
(2) and where should I add buttons (done , cancel) in CustomView or in ActionSheet ?
(3) and how I get the selected row when I click on Done button?

any suggestions ?

Thanks..

Comment: do you want your button display in table view or in actionsheet?

Comment: then add your button as a subview of actionsheet

Comment: n how can I get the selected row on button click ?

Comment: you have to take flag and when you click on any row the didSelectRow method will be called so in that method you can find the row and assign that row to the flag...and when you press "DONE" take value of that flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**

> when I click on any row, the selected row should come at center.

*Kindly provide me with more details on this issue i can't get it right.*

**(2)**

> and where should I add buttons (done , cancel) in CustomView or in ActionSheet ?

Add them in the UIActionSheet:

```
 UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button"     otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];
 popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
 [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
 [popupQuery release];
```

**(3)**

> get the selected row when I click on Done button?

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [MyTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

Comment: in my table view it displays exact 3 rows . if I select the 3rd row then selected row should come at center means 2 -- 3(selected) ---4 like that..

Comment: @Maulik : Alright you need to have a look at [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)

Answer (score 3):

ActionSheetDataSource.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ActionSheetDataSource:NSObject
{
NSMutableArray*otherButtonArr;
NSString*title;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray*otherButtonArr;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString*title;

@end
```

CustomActionSheet.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomActionSheetView.h"
#import "ActionSheetDataSource.h"
#import "CustomButton.h"

 @interface CustomActionSheet : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
 {
     id<CustomActionSheetDelegate> delegate;
    ActionSheetDataSource*dataSource;
//        ActionsheetType TYPE;
    IBOutlet UITableView*tblView;
 }

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView*tblView;
@property (nonatomic,retain)id<CustomActionSheetDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain)ActionSheetDataSource*dataSource;
//    @property (nonatomic)ActionsheetType TYPE;

-(IBAction)actionBtnExit:(UIButton*)sender;

@end
```

customActionsheet.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize dataSource;
//@synthesize TYPE;
@synthesize tblView;


  #pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[self dataSource] title];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 // Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 { 
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
   return [[self.dataSource otherButtonArr] count];
  }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
if ([[cell contentView] viewWithTag:25]) 
{
    [[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:25] removeFromSuperview];
}


    CustomButton*cButton= [[[self dataSource] otherButtonArr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [cButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [cButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.accessoryType =   (cButton.selected)?UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


  return cell;
  }

  #pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
CustomButton*cButton= [[[self dataSource] otherButtonArr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self didSelectedOption:[cButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
}

-(void)hideAction
{
[[self view] removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)actionBack
{
[self didSelectedOption:@"Go Back"];
}

-(IBAction)actionBtnExit:(UIButton*)sender
{
[self didSelectedOption:@"Go Back"];
}

-(void)didSelectedOption:(NSString*)option
{
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedOption:)]) 
{
    [[self delegate] didSelectedOption:option];
}
CGRect frame=[[self view] frame];
frame.origin =CGPointMake(frame.origin.x,frame.size.height+frame.origin.y);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"hideCustomActionSheetView" context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView  setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hideAction)];
[[self view] setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

CustomActionSheetView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ActionSheetDataSource.h"

typedef enum{
    ACTIONS,
    OPTIONS
}ActionsheetType;

@class CustomActionSheet;
@protocol CustomActionSheetDelegate;

@interface CustomActionSheetView : NSObject
{
}

+(void)loadActionSheetInView:(UIView*)view withDataSource:   (ActionSheetDataSource*)dataSource andDelegate:(id<CustomActionSheetDelegate>)delegate;
+(void)loadActionSheetInView:(UIView*)view withDataSource:(ActionSheetDataSource*)dataSource delegate:(id<CustomActionSheetDelegate>)delegate andType:(ActionsheetType)TYPE;
@end

@protocol CustomActionSheetDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)didSelectedOption:(NSString*)option;
@end
```

CustomActionSheetView.m

```
    +(void)loadActionSheetInView:(UIView*)view withDataSource:(ActionSheetDataSource*)dataSource andDelegate:(id<CustomActionSheetDelegate>)delegate
    {
    CustomActionSheet*actionSheet= [[CustomActionSheet alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomActionSheet" bundle:nil];
    [actionSheet setDelegate:delegate];
    [actionSheet setDataSource:dataSource];
    CGRect frame=[view frame];
    frame.size.height -= 20;
    frame.origin =CGPointMake(frame.origin.x,frame.size.height+frame.origin.y);
    [[actionSheet view] setFrame:frame];
    [[actionSheet tblView] reloadData];
    [view addSubview:[actionSheet view]];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"RS_showKeyboardAnimation" context:nil];   
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect frame2=[view frame];
    frame2.size.height -= 20;
    frame2.origin =CGPointMake(frame2.origin.x,10+frame2.origin.y);
    [[actionSheet view] setFrame:frame2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Now you can call all this from any view as below

exampleview.h

```
#import "ActionSheetDataSource.h"
#import "CustomActionSheet.h"

<CustomActionSheetDelegate>
```

exampleview.m

```
 -(void)calling
    {
        ActionSheetDataSource*dataSource=[[[ActionSheetDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];//mm
    [dataSource setTitle:@"I want to"];
    CustomButton*cBack=[CustomButton CustomButtonWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] andTitle:@"Go Back"];
   NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cBack ,nil];
    [dataSource setOtherButtonArr:arr];
    [CustomActionSheetView loadActionSheetInView:self.view withDataSource:dataSource andDelegate:self];

    }

    -(void)didSelectedOption:(NSString*)option
    {
     if([option isEqualToString:@"Go Back"])
        return;
     }
```

CustomButton.h
    #import

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
+(CustomButton*)CustomButtonWithColor:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)title;
+(CustomButton*)CustomButtonWithColor:(UIColor*)color title:(NSString*)title andSelectedState:(BOOL)state;
@end
```

CustomButton.m

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

+(CustomButton*)CustomButtonWithColor:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)title
{
CustomButton*btn=[[self class] buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
if (btn) 
{
    [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
}
return btn;
}

+(CustomButton*)CustomButtonWithColor:(UIColor*)color title:(NSString*)title andSelectedState:(BOOL)state
{
CustomButton*btn=[[self class] buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
if (btn) 
{
    [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [btn setSelected:state];
}
return btn;
}
@end
```